# get user's adress using altitude and coordination points

Tags: objective-c, xcode, google-maps, mkmapview

I was wondering if its possible to get a place name, adress or something other than the coordinates of the user when using MKMapView in xcode.

I would like to get something like : Starbucks cafe, 90210 or something like that using the coordinates.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's called [reverse geocoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_geocoding). You'll find plenty of questions about it right here on SO, and there are a number of web services out there that'll do it for you.